# Reuse or copy collision force

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

Whenever my character collides with an object, i add a rigidbody to that object; and i also would like to reapply the same force it should have received with the collision on the same point, so it reacts with physics.

This is my attempt so far, but force is way too much as all objects fly from the scene:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() == null) {
        collision.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForceAtPosition(collision.impulse, collision.contacts[0].point);
    }
}
```

I also tried with:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() == null) {
        collision.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForceAtPosition(collision.impulse / Time.fixedDeltaTime, collision.contacts[0].point);
    }
}
```

What i'm doing wrong/missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your point of collision might be to far from the origin of the object. 
Check:

- if the collision box is proportionnal to the object.
- the colision point makes sense with the actual position of the object.
- the mass of the rigidbody is adequate.

> Note that when position is far away from the center of the rigidbody
>   the applied torque will be unrealistically large.
>   [from unity doc page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html)

as for the colision interpretation in the code, i found this piece of code in this article describing [How to get the impact force of a collision in Unity](https://www.malgol.com/how-to-get-the-impact-force-of-a-collision-in-unity/)

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour {
private void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision) {
    float collisionForce = collision.impulse.magnitude / Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    if (collisionForce < 100.0F) {
        // This collision has not damaged anyone...
    }
    else if (collisionForce < 200.0F) {
        // Auch! This will take some damage.
    }
    else {
        // This collision killed me!
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: So adding the force by using the collision impulse divided by fixed delta is already correct?

Comment: I think using the delta time should be the correct implementation. I edited the answer with more details and  code implementation, hope it helps.